# Laravel 5. Whoops error page not displaying. Shows blank page

Tags: laravel-5

Very strange thing I ran into. Couldn't find anything on the internet so I am curious to whether this is a bug or not.

If my application runs in to an exception the Whoops error page with the stack trace is not being displayed.

However, if I comment out line 47 of Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler:

```
$this->log->error((string) $e);
```

it does appear?!

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to an exception taking place before the error handler is loaded. For example, it can happen when you have an issue with a `use` statement in a controller or within middleware.

It's quite rare, but because standard PHP errors are suppressed by Laravel it can make debugging things a little tricky. You can either enable them, or check the error logs of your server when it does happen (the HTTP response in this scenario will always be 500 which is a good clue).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following.

1. Check your php.ini and set display_error = on.
2. Check your config/app.php and set debug = true.For laravel 5 you can set it to the .env file.
3. Additionally you can make a composer update command.(strange but it works)

Answer (score 0):

Take following steps:

1. Ensure debug is set to true on .env file

   APP_DEBUG=true
2. Nope, still see the blank page?

   Grant 777 permission to the storage folder

   - sudo chmod 777 -R storage
3. Tried above command, but the page doesn't go away!

   Try granting a write permission to the storage folder

   - sudo chmod -R o+w storage
4. Grrr, still blank page?

   Have you forgotten to run composer install?

   - composer install
5. composer install didn't help

   Config might have been cached. Clear config cache by running following command

   - php artisan config:clear

For more check out this link: 
http://www.phplab.info/categories/laravel/whoops-looks-like-something-went-wrong

Thanks